# How to send ONLY one mail from OnError event handler in SSIS

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, ssis-2012, msbi

I have a package which contains several contains and tasks in it.I have used **Send Mail task in Error Event handler** to send mail if any error occurs during the load. But whenever error occurs in package, **Send Mail task** has been executing twice or thrice(sending mails) with different error description.
I need to receive **ONLY** one mail with all the error description instead of multiple mails.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSIS Package level OnError sends two emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528050/ssis-package-level-onerror-sends-two-emails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not immediately send a mail in your Event Handler, instead, accumulate all the errors first to a string array, then using another script task in your control flow, compose the mail body by "stitching" the items in the string array. Finally, use the "stitched" message in a send mail task in the control flow.

1. Create a variable of type object.
2. In your control flow, put all tasks inside a sequence container except the Send Mail Tasks.
3. Add an event handler for the On Error event of the sequence container created in #2, then add a script task that will store the value of System::ErrorDescription into a string array. Ensure that you don't overwrite the contents of the string array from the last error. Store the string array to a variable of type Object.
4. In the control flow, add a script task to "stitch" the contents of the string array into a single variable to use as the body of the Send Mail Task. Connect the script task to the Sequence Container via a Failure precedence constraint.
5. Add a Send Mail Task after the script task.

Comment: Instead of using Variable of object type,i have stored this Error Description in a table later i have used this table and kept all the Error description from it in mail body. anyways logic is same.thanks.. :-)

Comment: Email will be sent irrespective of success or failure?

Comment: Thanks for the help here! I am only stuck at the stitch together portion, not sure how to go about this...