# Duplicate log entries due to nested containers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Any simple way of solving the problem where you have a component and get the same log massage more than one time due to the fact that the component is nested inside other components (like a container and a data flow for example)

[image]

I found [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/289992/ssis-logging-duplicate-log-entries-due-to-nested-containers-cannot-be-easily-suppressed), where MS say it wont do anything about it, but its from 2007.
I dont really want to do the  workaround suggested, seems a lot of work.

Comment: See the answers to this question that is similar to yours:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2560452/236348

Comment: @WilliamToddSalzman I *think* Diego's goal is to make the native/out of the box logging behave much like your custom event handler check (+1 btw) without having to go through and set the Propagate property on everything.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The duplicate question applies to using the SSIS Events to perform an action and how to restrict it to just one usage. *This* question is about how one can use the native logging functionality to elicit the same behaviour. Were the OP using an `Execute SQL Task` in various Event Handlers to perform logging, it would be a duplicate. This is not the case and I believe the question to have been erroneously closed.

Comment: Second @Billinkc reopen.  After rereading the question more closely, Bill is right, my candidate duplicate is using event handlers while Diego is simply using logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For logging, if you chose to log to sql server, SSIS will create a Stored Proc 
(SQL 2005)

Proc Name: dbo.sp_dts_addlogentry

Table Name: dbo.sysdtslog90 (user table)

(SQL 2008)

Proc Name: dbo.sp_ssis_addlogentry

Table Name: dbo.sysssislog (system table)

You are free to modify this to filter out log entries (sql will recreate it if it is missing, but will not overwrite a self written version of the same name.)

The system generated version is simply an insert into of the parameters sent to the proc by SSIS.

You can add logic to follow the chain up the executionid to find parent objects and suppress logging for entries that have already been logged (you will want to handle the OnError event name in your code for this)  I usually pass OnPreExecute, OnPostExecute, OnError, and OnTaskFailed events into my logging proc.  By default, the proc also gets PackageStart and PackageEnd events.

That being said, I let all of these log fully to the table in sql then use summary and detail report to check the logging and see errors.  My report filters to show only the one error for each occurance rather than filtering on the input into the log file.   I also log all of my SSIS packages into a single database for configurations and logging that is included in every SSIS package.

Comment: thanks for the procedure's information. Didn't know that. Dont think I can do anything on the proc because it is called once per row, so I cant actually check for duplicates. Only solution would be to filter by the component's ID but I don't like this. can become very messy. I think I'll do like you and deal with it on the reporting. Thanks.