# SSIS On Error Event Handler sending multiple emails on error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have set up a Script Email task as part of the OnError Event Handler in a SSIS package. But on error the event handler sends multiple emails. Understanding the reason of that I tried to implement the solution suggested in the following thread but that is not working for me. I am having an issue similar to one of the commentators where condition `@[System::SourceID]== @[System::PackageID]` always evaluates to False so no email is being sent out at all now instead of multiple ones. I am using SQL Server 2012.

[SSIS send email on error sending multiple errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560452/ssis-send-email-on-error-sending-multiple-errors?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

PS: I could not add comment to this thread due to lack of reputation points, so I had to start a new one.

Thanks,
KK

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the package in the debugger to see if it's triggering the event handler multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

The way I have resolved the multiple exception issue in the past is

1. Only raise email / log errors from master packages
2. Add ErrorCounter variable and set to zero
3. Inside the OnError handler increase the on error count by 1
4. Add a precedence constraint expression @[User::ErrorCounter]<=1
5. Send email or log error from that precedence constraint

that way you will only record one error per set of parent / child package failures

Answer (score 0):

I always use @[System::SourceName] ==  @[System::PackageName]
[image]
[Enlarge](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rr_c3EGqZuc/U3Nw9KiTzUI/AAAAAAAAC-8/yx2ThJa4CXs/s1600/events03.jpg)